# How to extract the high-level features of YOLOv5?

Tags: object-detection, yolo, feature-extraction

I am faimilar with extracting the high-level features from any pretrained model for classification problem such as ResNet version, VGG, etc. It is easy to extract the features because there is a fully connected layer after the convolutional layers and the high-level features are usually extracted from the penultimate layer (the output of neurons of the layer before softmax layer).

Today, I spent a lot of time to understand how I can extract the high-level features from YOLOv5.

Firstly, I want to ask please, how do the high-level features look like? I mean what is the shape of the features, because I do not see any fully connected layer in the repository [here](https://github.com/ultralytics/yolov5/blob/868c0e9bbb45b031e7bfd73c6d3983bcce07b9c1/models/yolo.py).

Second question, from which layer should I extract the features of final predicted objects?

Thank you so much for any help! I am really stuck for a long time. :(

Comment: I recommend you read this StackExchange [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73440468/where-to-find-the-yolov5-feature-extractor).

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `export = True` at the yolo head. If the `net` is the `AutoShape` instance, you can achieve it by:

```
m = net.model.model.model[-1] if net.dmb else net.model.model[-1]
m.export = False  # Allow obtaining features after detection/segmentation head
```

Also, you might need to fix non maxima suppression to pass the correct features.